# Session login verification

Tags: php, html, session, model-view-controller, methods

I'm working this semester on a website project that manages refunds to clients.

Basically, the client fills a form and then gets serial number that identifies his form inputs.

I'm only on the very early stages of the project, and I chose to use the MVC architecture so that I avoid being confused when my website include dozens of files.

As I am a mathematics student, I can sometimes find some difficulties making connection between methods and files roles.

I currently work on the login part for users and I'm stuck in the user controller part as I haven't found any idea yet to verify the login and password of the user and make the connection if the identifiers are correct and pass on a message if not.

Here is my usersModel.php file :

```html
<?php 

function login($login, $pswd){
  $c = Database :: connect();
  $q = $c -> prepare( "SELECT * FROM users WHERE login=? AND mdp=?" );
  $q -> execute( array($login , $pswd)));
  Database :: disconnect();
}

function getUserIdbyLogin($login){
  $c = Database :: connect();
  $q = $c -> prepare( "SELECT uid FROM users WHERE login=?" );
  $q -> execute(array($_GET['login']));
  Database :: disconnect();
}

function getUserRolebyId($id){
  $c = Database :: connect();
  $q = $c -> prepare( "SELECT role FROM users WHERE id=?" );
  $q -> execute(array($_GET['role']));
  Database :: disconnect();
}


?>
```

then my usersController.php file :

```html
<?php
require 'model\usersModel.php';

if(isset($_POST['login']) && isset($_POST['pswd'])) {
 $log = $_POST['login'];
 $mdp = $_POST['pswd'];

}




?>
```

I don't know how to verify the login and password using the login() function I created above, can you help me by giving me some tips ?

Thanks in advance